# How to scale image in ACTION_DOWN without calling ACTION_MOVE in android?

Tags: android, touch-event

I want to scale the image in `ACTION_DOWN` but at the same time I `ACTION_MOVE` will call and my logic of moving image will execute. But I don't want to call `ACTION_MOVE` after `ACTION_DOWN`. I want to put some condition which is prevent to enter into `MOVE` action but what and how that I don't know.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why not call your logic only when the appropriate action takes place? Something like:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
    switch(e.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //scale here
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //move here
        break;
    }
}
```